# Pandas apply function taking up to 10min (numba doesnot help)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have got a very simple function to apply to each row of my dataframe:

```
def distance_ot(fromwp,towp,pl,plee):
`  if fromwp[0:3]==towp[0:3]:
    sxcord=pl.loc[fromwp,"XCORD"]
    sycord=pl.loc[fromwp,"YCORD"]
    excord=pl.loc[towp,"XCORD"]
    eycord=pl.loc[towp,"YCORD"] 
    x=np.abs(excord-sxcord);   y=np.abs(eycord-sycord)  
    distance=x+y
    return distance
   else:
    x1=np.abs(plee.loc[fromwp[0:3],"exitx"]-pl.loc[fromwp,"XCORD"])
    y1=np.abs(plee.loc[fromwp[0:3],"exity"]-pl.loc[fromwp,"YCORD"])
    x2=np.abs(plee.loc[fromwp[0:3],"exitx"]-plee.loc[towp[0:3],"entryx"])
    y2=np.abs(plee.loc[fromwp[0:3],"exity"]-plee.loc[towp[0:3],"entryy"])
    x3=np.abs(plee.loc[towp[0:3],"entryx"]-pl.loc[towp,"XCORD"])
    y3=np.abs(plee.loc[towp[0:3],"entryy"]-pl.loc[towp,"YCORD"])
    distance=x1+x2+x3+y1+y2+y3
    return distance
```

With this line it is called:

```
pot["traveldistance"]=pot.apply(lambda row: distance_ot(fromwp=row["from_wpadr"],towp=row["to_wpadr"],pl=pl,plee=plee),axis=1)
```

Where: `fromwp` and `towp` are both strings and `xcord` and `ycord` are floats. I tried using numba but for some reasons it does not enhance this performance. Any suggestions?

Thanks to  caiohamamura hint hereby the solution:

```
distance_ot(pl=pl,plee=plee)
pot.ix[pot.from_wpadr.str[0:3]==pot.to_wpadr.str[0:3],"traveldistance"]=pot["distance1"]
pot.ix[pot.from_wpadr.str[0:3]!=pot.to_wpadr.str[0:3],"traveldistance"]=pot["distance2"] 

def distance_ot(pl,plee):
    from_df = pl.loc[pot["from_wpadr"]]
    to_df = pl.loc[pot["to_wpadr"]]
    sxcord=from_df["XCORD"].values
    sycord=from_df["YCORD"].values
    excord=to_df["XCORD"].values
    eycord=to_df["YCORD"].values
    x=np.abs(excord-sxcord);   y=np.abs(eycord-sycord)  
    pot["distance1"]=x+y
    from_df2=plee.loc[pot["from_wpadr"].str[0:3]]
    to_df2=plee.loc[pot["to_wpadr"].str[0:3]]
    x1=np.abs(from_df2["exitx"].values-from_df["XCORD"].values)
    y1=np.abs(from_df2["exity"].values-from_df["YCORD"].values)
    x2=np.abs(from_df2["exitx"].values-to_df2["entryx"].values)
    y2=np.abs(from_df2["exity"].values-to_df2["entryy"].values)
    x3=np.abs(to_df2["entryx"].values-to_df["XCORD"].values)
    y3=np.abs(to_df2["entryy"].values-to_df["YCORD"].values)

    pot["distance2"]=x1+x2+x3+y1+y2+y3
```

Comment: Well...how many rows do yoyou have 1...1000...100000000000?

Comment: Apply is almost like for loop, so it will be slow. You have to vectorize yourself the function so that it will calculate all the distances at once receiving the whole `fromwp` and `towp` array and then assign the result to `pot["traveldistance"]`. For more detailed solution you will have to explain the function, `pl` and `plee` dataframes.

Comment: You should try to vectorize the function yourself and if you have any trouble post another question. The solution is: vectorize to calculate all the distances at once (without loops of course).

Comment: Thanks Caiomamura! You ideas were helpfull and I fixxed my code. I updated the question with correct line which saves up to 500 sec!

Answer (score 0):

Vectorize the `distance_ot` function to calculate all distances at once. I would begin populating a from_df and a to_df like the following:

```
import numpy as np

from_df = pl.loc[np.in1d(pl.loc.index, pot["from_wpadr"])
to_df = pl.loc[np.in1d(pl.loc.index, pot["to_wpadr"])
```

Then you can continue as in your function:

```
sxcord=from_df["XCORD"]
sycord=from_df["YCORD"]
excord=to_df["XCORD"]
eycord=to_df["YCORD"] 
x=np.abs(excord-sxcord);   y=np.abs(eycord-sycord)  
distances=x+y
```

This will calculate all the distances at once. Your if clause can also be vectorized, your results will be calculated into different arrays, those which match the if clause and those that doesn't, you just have to keep track of the boolean array, so you can put them together in the dataframe afterwards:

```
first_three_equals = np.char.ljust(pot["from_wpadr"].values.astype(str), 3) \
                     == np.char.ljust(pot["to_wpadr"].values.astype(str), 3)
```